# parse and sort multiple Facebook json feeds by key

Tags: php, arrays, json, facebook, sorting

I'm trying to fetch multiple Facebook feeds and display them in chronological order

all objects in the json feed will have "created_time" so I want to use this as a key to parse and display all the objects in chronological order regardless of what feed they come from

heres my code

```
$urls = array(
//FEED1
'https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/posts?fields=message,full_picture,description,link,picture,source,name,type,status_type,caption,created_time,permalink_url&limit=10&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN',
//FEED 2
'https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/posts?fields=message,full_picture,description,link,picture,source,name,type,status_type,caption,created_time,permalink_url&limit=10&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN',
//FEED 3
'https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/posts?fields=message,full_picture,description,link,picture,source,name,type,status_type,caption,created_time,permalink_url&limit=10&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN');

$results = array();
```

And then I do

```
foreach($urls as $index => $url){
$DataContent = file_get_contents($url);
$infoData = json_decode($DataContent, true);

foreach ($infoData['data'] as $Data){
    $FBPostCreatedTime = $Data['created_time'];

    /*PARSE THE DATA HERE*/
    }
}
```

The results of this code outputs each feed one by one,

how do I use $FBPostCreatedTime to merge all the feed data and display it in chronological order?

Thanks

Comment: merge all feeds into one array and then sort it

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you want to do, but, I'm assuming you want to sort an array by a date or time. This is how I would alter the `foreach()` loop in your code:

```
$NewData = array(); // Will hold an altered array. 

foreach ($infoData['data'] as $Data) {

    $NewData[$Data['created_time']] = $Data;
}

ksort($NewData);
```

`$NewData` will be an associative array that uses the `created_time` value from `$Data` as the key name for each row of data. Running `ksort()` on this array will sort the array using this key. You can also use `krsort()` to sort the array keys in reverse.

This assumes `created_time` is formatted as a SQL date string: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, for example: `2017-04-26 14:30:00`.

Comment: I want to collect the data from the multiple urls (feeds) and sort through that collective data display the posts from those feeds in a single timeline fashion (newest at top, oldest at bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Using `created_time` as an array key will probably be fine most of the time, but on the off chance more than one post has the same value for `created_time`, the subsequent posts will overwrite the existing value at that key. In order to avoid that possibility, you can just append all the posts to one array

```
foreach ($infoData['data'] as $Data) {
    $allPosts[] = $Data;
}
```

And then after your *outer* `foreach` loop finishes, `usort` the result.

```
usort($allPosts, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['created_time'] <=> $b['created_time'];
});
```

Comment: Facebook return paramater created_time as 2012-12-13T04:14:29+0000. How to read this datetime ? What does mean this datetime ?